# How to prove $\lim|a_n|=|a|$  does not mean $\lim a_n =a$ exist

Tags: real-analysis

It is easy to prove that if $\lim a_n=a$  then  $\lim|a_n|=|a|$ by using $||a_n |-|a||\le|a_n-a|$, but I can't show that the converse is false.

Comment: Note that the converse is always true iff $a=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Look at the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$.

Comment: Note that you have to impose that $lim a_n$ doesn't exist!

Comment: do you mean choose (a_n)= ((-1)^n) ?

Comment: @user27217 Yes, exactly.

Comment: thanks, it suits now. simple things sometimes being hard to see

Comment: @chessmath: Actually, the converse is false even if $\lim a_n$ does exist: consider $a_n=1$ for all $n$, but $a=-1$.

Comment: But u have to keep in mind that it holds when a=0, and when a is not zero the sequence will have a signal for n large enough!